# Cannot logout from Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, xfce, logout

I have migrated from Kubuntu to Xubuntu (18.04). Now, my biggest problem is that I cannot logout from my session. Regardless of using GUI or terminal approach, I experience session referesh in which all my applications are still open.

I didn't have this problem when I was on Kubuntu.